# SSAS 2012 visual bug?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, ssas, cube

Has anyone else seen this? [missing dsv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42BLS.png)

Normally when you are looking at a DIM in SSAS you have three sections to work in. 
1) Attributes: These are the values you are including in your model
2) Hierarchys: If you build a hierarchy here is where it is viewed
3) Data Source View: This shows the source of the DIM and all the attributes loaded into the DSV are included.

Why is my DSV box empty?

I'm using TFS source control. I've deleted the local project and repulled the latest version but I'm still seeing this issue.

I'll submit an offical bug on microsoft's website.

If you have seen this how have you fixed it? I need to add new attributes to my DIM and I can't do that if I can't see the source table in the DIM...I'd prefer to not have to recreate ever DIM because of some bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this if anyone else comes across it. It has to do with having more than one version of Visual Studios installed on the server at a time and using different versions.

This article goes into detail on the issue. The article talks about changing the XLM code for the .dsv file and the .cube file. Specifically for the DIMs you will need to change the code there as well. Quite annoying...at least there is a way to fix it.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlblog/2015/06/10/ssas-dsv-com-error-from-ssdt-ssas-design-data-source-view/

TLDR: VS 2012 and VS 2014 conflict with each other with their dll files. You will need to go into the XML code and change the leading binary string to the version of VS that you want to use.